# The port is closed when I interrupt the telnet client

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I start one listening port on Server1 by using `nc -l -p 9999` and using `telnet Server1 9999` on the other machine for building a connection.

I want to know why I stop the telnet client and then the port is also closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the -k flag.

Taken from the nc man pages:

```
   -k, --keep-open (Accept multiple connections) .
       Normally a listening server accepts only one connection and then
       quits when the connection is closed. This option makes it accept
       multiple simultaneous connections and wait for more connections
       after they have all been closed. It must be combined with --listen.
       In this mode there is no way for Ncat to know when its network
       input is finished, so it will keep running until interrupted. This
       also means that it will never close its output stream, so any
       program reading from Ncat and looking for end-of-file will also
       hang.
```

Comment: Many thanks! But I still curious about how the port will know the connection is interrupted ? Is it because this connection is based on the TCP protocol ?

Comment: Yeah, the status of the connection will  change from established to close wait or listening.